# How to design and implement an asymmetric loss function for regression?

Tags: regression, error, loss-functions

### Problem

In regression one usually computes the **mean squared error** (MSE) for a sample:
$$
\text{MSE} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(g(x_i) - \widehat{g}(x_i)\right)^2
$$
to measure the quality of a predictor.

Right now I'm working on a regression problem where the goal is to predict the price customers are willing to pay for a product given a number of numeric features. If the predicted price is too high no customer will buy the product, but the monetary loss is low because the price can simply be decremented. Of course it should not be too high as then the product may not be bought for a long time. On the other hand if the predicted price is too low, the product will be bought quickly without the chance to adjust the price.

In other words the learning algorithm should predict slightly higher prices which can be decremented if necessary rather than underestimating the true price which will result in an immediate monetary loss.

### Question

How would you design an error metric incorporating this cost asymmetry?

---

### Possible Solution

A way to define an asymmetric loss function would be to simply multiply by a weight:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \alpha - \mathbb{1}_{(g(x_i) - \widehat{g}(x_i)) < 0} \right|\cdot \left(g(x_i) - \widehat{g}(x_i)\right)^2
$$
with $\alpha \in (0,1)$ being the parameter we can adjust to change the degree of asymmetry. I've found it [here](https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/conference/download.cgi?db_name=ESAM09&paper_id=194). This seems like the most straight forward thing to do, while maintaining the quadratic loss.

Comment: +1, I think this is a good question. However, I would say that in regression, we usually use *squared error*, rather than *mean squared error* for loss; furthermore, I note that in the formula you list, you have the expected squared error, not the expected *mean* squared error, as there is no division by $n$.

Comment: @gung it appears now that it has been edited to be MSE.  I don't fully understand your point though since minimizing the sum of squared errors is equivalent to minimizing MSE.

Comment: It is not the same thing. The _expected mean squared (prediction) error_ is independent of a specific sample. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Alternative_usages)

Comment: @MichaelChernick, FTR, I think this is a good question, which has been stated clearly & coherently, & acknowledge that I'm being a bit nit-picky. What I'm getting at is (as you know) fitting a regression (ie, solving for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$) is done (by default) by minimizing the [OLS loss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation), SSE. You're right that MSE *could* be used equivalently b/c dividing by a constant won't affect the ordering of candidate betas.

Comment: Another fact is that MSE (more often RMSE) is often used to assess the quality of a fitted model (although, again, SSE could be used equivalently). The thing is, this question seems (to me anyway) to be about how to think about / redesign the *loss function*, so that the fitted betas are different than they would have been by default, rather than about how to think differently about the quality of a model that has *already* been fit.

Comment: @Kiudee, if my interpretation of your Q is right, what would you think about editing it to add the [tag:loss-functions] tag, & possibly revising the title to something like: "How to design & implement an asymmetric loss function for regression"? I won't make the edits myself in case you disagree w/ them.

Comment: I think gung's suggested title is more informative about the question.  I think I assumed that was what you were driving at when I gave my answer.

Comment: @gung, that is indeed a better title, thanks. I've made the edit.

Comment: For reference, I've seen quantile regression suggested when you want asymmetric loss functions, see [Berk, 2011](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10940-010-9098-2), PDF [here](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~berkr/loss%20copy.pdf).

Comment: Do you have any constraints on function (differentiability, etc.)?

Comment: As I'm using a variety of learning algorithms to tackle this problem, the function should be differentiable at least once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, quantile regression uses an asymmetric loss function ( linear but with different slopes for positive and negative errors). The quadratic (squared loss) analog of quantile regression is expectile regression.

You can google quantile regression for the references. For expectile regression see the R package [expectreg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expectreg/index.html) and the references in the reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of unequal weighting is often done in classification problems with two classes.  The Bayes rule can be modifed using a loss function that that weights the loss higher for one error than the other.  This will lead to a rule that produces unequal error rates.

In regression it would certainly be possible to construct a weight function such as a weighted sum of squares that will give some weight to the negative errors and a higher weight to the positive ones.  This would be similar to weighted least square but a little different because weighted least squares is intended for problems where the error variance is not constant over the space of possible values for the predictor variables.  In that case the weights are higher for the points where the error variance is known to be small and higher where the error variance is known to be large. This of course will lead to values for the regression parameters that are different from what OLS would give you.